# установка библиотеки go, ошибка go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory и no required module provides package

Tags: golang, библиотеки

Хотел установить [библиотеку](https://github.com/qax-os/excelize).

Инструкция такая:

> Installation
>
> ```sh
> go get github.com/xuri/excelize
> ```
>
> If your packages are managed using Go Modules, please install with following command.
>
> ```sh
> go get github.com/xuri/excelize/v2
> ```

Пробую, ошибка:

```
go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory.
        'go get' is no longer supported outside a module.
```

Сгонял по ссылке библиотеки, github пишет 404. Не уверен, что так должно быть.

**UPD**
Сделал следующее:

```sh
go install github.com/xuri/excelize/v2@latest
```

что-то установилось, но всё равно код не собирается, ошибка:

```
no required module provides package github.com/xuri/excelize/v2
```

РОДНОЙ [README](https://github.com/qax-os/excelize#basic-usage)

Comment: Не знаю у вас в инструкции установки автор проекта некий `xuri`, на самом деле `qax-os`. Может поможет.

Comment: Видимо нужно `go get github.com/qax-os/excelize`

Comment: Нет я ошибся, надо написать `go get github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проще говоря, если совсем непонятно:

1. создайте папку проекта `mkdir my_proj`
2. в папке `go mod init main`
3. создаёте `main.go`
4. устанавливайте библиотеку как и хотели, обязательно внутри папки `go get github.com/user/my_lib`

Answer (score 1):

Эта ошибка говорит что у вас нету файла `go.mod`.

Структура должна быть примерно такая:

```
 test_module
   go.mod
  ...
```

Вы должны находиться в папке `test_pkg` (Это и есть модуль go).

Далее в ней вы вводите какую нужно команду, например:

```sh
go get github.com/xuri/excelize
```

Должен создаться файл `go.sum` и всё должно работать.

Подробнее о файле `go.mod` в [документации](https://go.dev/doc/modules/gomod-ref).

Comment: $go get github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize
go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory.
        'go get' is no longer supported outside a module.
        To build and install a command, use 'go install' with a version,
        like 'go install example.com/cmd@latest'
        For more information, see https://golang.org/doc/go-get-install-deprecation
        or run 'go help get' or 'go help install'.

У вас вероятно старая версия go в которой get работает, инструкции из ошибки я пробовал выполнить и описал в вопросе:)

Comment: Вы обратите внимание на ошибку, она говорит не то что не удаётся установить пакет, а что вы находитесь не в go пакете.

Comment: а что значит не в проекте? как в него войти?

Comment: @SpaceResearcher Я переписал ответ, надеюсь поможет.